# Ruby on Rails - Associations error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i've got a problem about association in my RoR project; i explain:

i've got two tables:

- **Admin** - Created with Devise.
- **Contacts** - Created with the rails standard console command `rails g scaffold`.

The Admin table have an 1:n association with the Contact's one so in their respective classes:

**Admin:**

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

**Contact**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :admin
        validates :nome, :cognome, :indirizzo_abitazione, 
                  :numero_civico, :indirizzo_email, :prefisso_cellulare, :cellulare, presence: true
        validates :indirizzo_email, :indirizzo_email_2, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
end
```

When i create one contact the first thing that i need to know is the id of the Admin that is creating it so i modified the 'create' method in the contacts_controller whit this

```
    def create
        @admin = Admin.find_by id: current_admin.id

        @contact = @admin.contacts.build(:admin_id => @admin.id)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @contact.save
            format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end

  end
```

when i try to create a contact (the submit button action), after i filled all my fileds i recive lots of validation errors despite all my fields are valid.
So i think that none of the parameters of the fields are passed during the create method.

I checked the contact_params method but all the fields are included:

```
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:nome, :cognome, :indirizzo_abitazione, :numero_civico, :indirizzo_email, :indirizzo_email_2, :prefisso_cellulare, :cellulare, :telefono_casa)
end
```

where am i wrong?

Also i add here the _form.html.erb code

```
  <%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:nome].present? == true ? "has-error" : "" %>" >
    <%= f.label :nome , :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :nome, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:cognome].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :cognome, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :cognome, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:indirizzo_abitazione].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :indirizzo_abitazione, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :indirizzo_abitazione, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:numero_civico].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :numero_civico, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :numero_civico, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:indirizzo_email].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :indirizzo_email, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :indirizzo_email, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:indirizzo_email_2].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :indirizzo_email_2, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :indirizzo_email_2, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:prefisso_cellulare].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :prefisso_cellulare, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :prefisso_cellulare, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:cellulare].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :cellulare, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :cellulare, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:telefono_casa].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>">
    <%= f.label :telefono_casa, :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :telefono_casa, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your form code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your issue is in your `create` method when you build the new contact:

```
@contact = @admin.contacts.build(:admin_id => @admin.id)
```

The code above doesn't include your `contact_params` and therefore wouldn't pass validation. You're only building a contact with the `admin_id`. Your code would have to look something like below to pass validation:

```
@contact = @admin.contacts.build(contact_params)
```

Also notice that you don't need to include `:admin_id => @admin.id` in `build` since you're creating the contact through the `@admin`. Rails is smart enough to know to associate that new contact with `@admin`!